# how to excute a job at a certain time

Tags: linux

I am new to Linux, and I would like help with a script. I want the script to create a file and give everyone permission to read, write, and execute it and after one minute I want the permission to be read only and to echo a message "you no longer have access".

I have tried the following and it creates and gives the permissions but does to echo the message "you no longer have access "..

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter time"
read time

touch bin/jozat
echo chmod 777 bin/jozat | at now + 1 minutes
echo chmod 700 bin/jozat | at now + 2 minutes && echo "you no longer have access"
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [at(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at).

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to use `at` but I'd bet your `echo` would send output for some log file. Also, don't you want to send the `echo` after updating the permissions? Your script outputs it just after registering the permissions changing in `at`, not when the permissions are changed.

I would replace it with `wall` which sends the message to all users in all terminals. So, I'd write

```
echo 'chmod 700 bin/jozat && echo "you no longer have access" | wall' | at now + 2 minutes
```

instead of

```
echo chmod 700 bin/jozat | at now + 2 minutes && echo "you no longer have access"
```

Note that all the command `chmod 700 bin/jozat && echo "you no longer have access" | wall` is between single quotes.

Is that a good solution for you?

**Edit**: the `wall` command sends the message to *all* users in *all* terminals. If you want to send the message only to the user executing the code, you can use the `write` command with the current username:

```
echo 'chmod 700 bin/jozat && echo "you no longer have access" | write `whoami`' | at now + 2 minutes
```

Comment: thanks brandizzi .i think that might do .will try it in a minute

Comment: thanks very much brandizzi .i tested it it worked with the wall .thanks again

Comment: Glad to help. BTW, have you seen my last update? There is a solution that does not show the messages to all users, but only for the current one. It can be better for you and is not complex at all.